# is there a special way to send MM7 soap request to MMSC for sending mms to Android devices

Tags: java, soap, mms, mms-gateway, mm7

We use a MM7 to send the request to MMSC for sending MMS.
Receiving user has an Android phone and He doesn't get the MMS.
But when Receiving user has a feature phone he gets the MMS.

Confusing here. please help.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you should specially handle on your MM7 message to make it work with Android.

What do you mean with "But when Receiving user has a feature phone he gets the MMS"? You can check following steps to troubleshoot.

- Check if phone can receive multimedia messages from other sources, try to send a multimedia message to your android phone from another phone. If not, check MMS settings on your android phone.
- Check status of message on MMSC side. If you can access server you can check network dump and extract your message.
- Request for delivery reports while submitting your MM7 message